# matching strings with database fields django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I django how can we check particular word is present in the database.
for example if database **classs** column contains '**hello,welcome,world**'.if I send a request 
**?q=welcome**
how can I check particular 'welcome' is present in my database **classs** column or not?

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from airapp.models import Travel
from django.db.models import Q

def search_form(request):
    return render(request, 'search_form.html')


def search(request):
    if 'f' in request.GET and request.GET['f']:
        q = request.GET['f']
        r = request.GET['t']
        s = request.GET['c']


        books = Travel.objects.filter(Q(classs__contains=s),
                                       froms__icontains=q,to=r)
        return render(request, 'search_results.html',
            {'books': books, 'query': q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Travel(models.Model):
    froms = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    to = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    classs = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=3330)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.froms
```

**seach_form.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#search-form").submit(function() {
                var from = $("#search-form :input[name='f']").val();
                var tos  = $("#search-form :input[name='t']").val();
                var clas = $("#search-form :input[name='c']").val();
                $.get("/search/", { f : from, t:tos, c:clas })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        $("#search-result").html(data);
                        $("#search-result").show();
                    });
                return false;
            })});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="search-form">
        FROM<input type="text" name="f"><br>
        TO<input type="text" name="t"><br>
        CLASS<input type="text" name="c"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

    <div id="search-result" style="display:none">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I check it django queries.

Comment: a Q object like Q(classs__icontains=q) should work. What is not working in your view?

Comment: It did not checking  whether welcome is my database classs column or not.In my html CLASS field if I only type 'welc' then also I getting output.I think there is something wrong in  query checking.I want to know how can we check particular substring is present in the database column using django queries.

Answer (score 1):

First, the difference between `contains` and `icontains` is just that `icontains` is the case-insensitive version of `contains`. Both lookups match partial strings, e.g.

```
Entry.objects.get(headline__contains='Lennon')
```

corresponds to SQL

```
SELECT ... WHERE headline LIKE '%Lennon%';
```

(from the Django docs)

if you do not want to match substrings, but exact strings in a column, use `exact` or `iexact`, respectively.

If your classs column contains multiple comma-separated entries, it is a bit more tricky, I guess.
You could make sure that every entries ends with a comma (also the last one), and then query for "welcome," for example (altough a bit hacky). I am however still not sure if this is actually the problem you want to solve.